# Localstack java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials

Tags: java, localstack

I would like to make some testes using localstack (SQS) in Spring Boot with a local docker container, so i'm using the LocalStackContainer to talk to my local docker container, but when i run the tests a weird exceptions happens. First i will show the code and second the stack trace.

The code: here i try to make a connection to the local docker with the image of localstack **v 0.11.6** and SQS as the service. In this line, i got the exception.

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.localstack.LocalStackContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@SpringBootTest(classes = SqsConsumer.class)
public class SqsConsumerTest {

    public static LocalStackContainer localStackContainer = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.11.6"))
            .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.SQS);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initLocalStack() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        localStackContainer.start();

        localStackContainer.execInContainer("awslocal", "sqs", "create-queue", "--queue-name", "image-sqs");
    }

}
```

the Exception/Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials

at br.com.imageprocessor.SqsConsumerTest.<clinit>(SqsConsumerTest.java:27)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 18 more
```

Well, the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>localstack</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've already checked the running docker container and i think everthing is ok from there. Its kind of weird this problem, i've checked the dependencies and its likely to be the problem but i didn't found any valid dependency for that.

EDIT:
After using another dependency from maven, it worked. Thanks everybody.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.142</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.142</version>
</dependency>
```

Probably related to this question: [JUnit AWSCredentials NoClassDefFoundError with LocalStackContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017812/junit-awscredentials-noclassdeffounderror-with-localstackcontainer)

Edit: changed the artifact id to aws-java-sdk-sqs from aws-java-sdk-s3

Comment: In my case I'm using SQS but after searching in maven i found this out and it worked.
`<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
   <version>1.12.142</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Oh right, my bad. I'll update the answer for future reference.